# Mulitibib not linking to all .bib files wanted

Tags: bibtex, subdividing, multibib

I am running LaTeX on a Mac and am having problems trying to use the `multibib` package.

the code I am running is (linking to relevant .bib files):

```
\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{h}{Reference List 1}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliographystyleh{plain}
.....

%\bibliographystyleh{plain}
\bibliographyh{references}

\newpage
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{designstudy}
```

However, only the references linked to the normal bibliography come out and not those linked to the one i've called h?

I've tried to compile it multiple times but it still doesn't find the other reference database.

Answer (score 4):

you have to run `bibtex` on each subbib:

```
pdflatex <file>
bibtex <file>
bibtex h
pdflatex <file>
pdflatex <file>
```

the first `bibtex` run is for the default bib and the second for the `h` bib

A complete example, saved as `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{Books}{List of Books}
\begin{document}
Articles: \cite{article-full} and \cite{article-crossref}.
%
Books: \citeBooks{inbook-minimal} and \citeBooks{inbook-full}.

\bibliographystyleBooks{plain}
\bibliographyBooks{xampl}

\renewcommand\refname{Articles}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

run it with

```
pdflatex test
bibtex test
bibtex Books
pdflatex test
pdflatex test
```

then it gives the output:

[image]

Comment: how to do run bibtex h though?

Comment: ie what do you have to click/press to do each of these commands?

Comment: on a mac open a `terminal` go into your documents directory and run it by hand.

Comment: it then says there is no h.aux file?

Comment: post your complete example.

Comment: vzo11:~ Valerie$ pdflatex <Desing Study Project>
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
vzo11:~ Valerie$ bibtex <Design Study Project>
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
vzo11:~ Valerie$ bibtex h
I couldn't open file name `h.aux'
vzo11:~ Valerie$ pdflatex <Design Study Project>
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
vzo11:~ Valerie$ pdflatex <Design Study Project>
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
vzo11:~ Valerie$

Comment: that's not an example! See my edit, you can run it. It uses a bibliography which is present in each TeX distribution.